# Memory leak from PODS

Tags: spring-boot, java-memory-leaks

We have some rest services which is going out of memory frequently.
I was doing code review and saw heavy usage of static methods.
Can that be an issue ?

Java 8, spring-boot 2.1.5
How do I debug this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Get the **Heap Dump** by using **jvisualvm** file.

> Download the **Eclipse Memory Analyzer** and start analysis the below
>   factors
>
> 1. Heap
> 2. Garbage Collection
> 3. OutOfMemory

Please visit [this](https://dzone.com/articles/java-heap-dump-analyzer-1)